# Splitting SQL column into multiple columns based on value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a table like the below

```
Opp_ID     Role_Name     Role_User_Name
---------------------------------------
1          Lead          Person_one
1          Developer     Person_two
1          Developer     Person_three
1          Owner         Person_four
1          Developer     Person_five
```

I now need to split the Role_Name column to be 3 different columns based on the values. I need to make sure there are no `NULL` values so the table should like the below

```
Opp_ID     Lead        Developer     Owner
--------------------------------------------------
1          Person_one  Person_two    Person_four
1          Person_one  Person_three  Person_four
1          Person_one  Person_five   Person_four
```

My code is currently:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    CASE WHEN Role_Name = 'Lead' THEN Role_User_Name ELSE NULL END AS Lead,
    CASE WHEN Role_Name = 'Developer' THEN Role_User_Name ELSE NULL END AS Developer,
    CASE WHEN Role_Name = 'Owner' THEN Role_User_Name ELSE NULL END AS Owner
FROM 
    [table1]
WHERE 
    Role_Name IN ('Lead','Developer','Owner')
```

Unfortunately this returns these results:

```
Opp_ID     Lead        Developer     Owner
-------------------------------------------
1          Person_one  NULL          NULL
1          NULL        Person_two    NULL
1          NULL        Person_three  NULL
1          NULL        NULL          Person_four
1          NULL        Person_five   NULL
```

I assume to get this working you need to join the code back on itself but I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: What DBMS are you using

Comment: This is a `PIVOT` operation, but how that is accomplished will depend on the database you are using.

Comment: Hi, I am using SQL Server 2017

Comment: In your `ELSE NULL` why don't you put `ELSE Role_User_Name` ? Also what should be the result in the NULL values of Developer in your last example?

Comment: I was wrong. You don't need a `PIVOT` but a couple of self-`JOIN`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply each developer and lead across your owners for an `Opp_ID`, you'll want something like:

```
SELECT o.opp_id
    , o.Role_User_Name AS Owner
    , l.Role_User_Name AS Lead
    , d.Role_User_Name AS Developer
FROM t1 AS o
LEFT OUTER JOIN t1 l ON o.opp_id = l.opp_id AND l.Role_Name = 'Lead'
LEFT OUTER JOIN t1 d ON o.opp_id = d.opp_id AND d.Role_Name = 'Developer'
WHERE o.Role_Name = 'Owner'
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=da4daea062534245bed474f93ffafbb7

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4e264e56a5295e18b4272b112725cf75 <<< Multiple Owners and Leads, and an `Opp_ID` without a Lead.

Answer (score 1):

You can just switch to aggregation:

```
SELECT ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Role_Name = 'Lead' THEN Role_User_Name END) AS Lead,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Role_Name = 'Developer' THEN Role_User_Name END) AS Developer,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Role_Name = 'Owner' THEN Role_User_Name END) AS Owner
FROM [table1]
WHERE  Role_Name IN ('Lead', 'Developer', 'Owner')
GROUP BY ID;
```

If you could have multiple people, you might want to use `STRING_AGG()`.

Note that I removed the `ELSE NULL`.  This is redundant.  With no `ELSE` clause, the `CASE` expression returns `NULL` when there is no match.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **[first_value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** function on **[Pivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)** results like below

<kbd>**[See working demo](http://rextester.com/QNWO46619)**</kbd>

```
select 
    opp_id,
    lead=COALESCE([lead],FIRST_VALUE([Lead]) over( order by opp_id )),
    Developer=COALESCE([Developer],FIRST_VALUE([Developer]) over( order by opp_id )),
    Owner=COALESCE([Owner],FIRST_VALUE([Owner]) over( order by opp_id ))
from 
(select opp_id,Role_Name,
 Role_User_Name,
 rn=row_number() over( partition by Role_Name order by (select 1))
 from
 table1)
 src
pivot
(max(Role_user_name) for role_name in ([Lead],[Developer],[Owner]))p
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use cross join

```
select o.opp_id,
   o.role_user_name o, 
   l.role_user_name l, 
   d.role_user_name d
from t1 o cross join t1 l cross join t1 d
where o.role_name = 'Owner' 
   and l.role_name = 'Lead' 
   and d.role_name = 'Developer'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0cv2.jpg)